# Error inserting into temporary table

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a query but I get an error:

Query:

```
INSERT #tableN (ID,NAME,Value) 
  SELECT 1 , 'subject', SUM(subject), 2, 'age', SUM(age), 
         3, 'sex', SUM(sex), 4, 'test_time', SUM(test_time) 
  FROM taleParker
```

I get the following error:

> Msg 203, Level 16, State 2, Line 61
>   The name 'INSERT  #tableN
>   (ID,NAME,Value) SELECT  1 , 'subject',
>   SUM(subject),2 , 'age', SUM(age),3 ,
>   'sex', SUM(sex),4 , 'test_time',
>   SUM(test_time),' is not a valid
>   identifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your temporary table has three columns - yet your `SELECT` to insert has way more....

You need to break this up into several `INSERTs`:

```
INSERT #tableN (ID,NAME,Value) 
  SELECT 1 , 'subject', SUM(subject)
  FROM taleParker

INSERT #tableN (ID,NAME,Value) 
  SELECT 2, 'age', SUM(age)
  FROM taleParker

INSERT #tableN (ID,NAME,Value) 
  SELECT 3, 'sex', SUM(sex)
  FROM taleParker

INSERT #tableN (ID,NAME,Value) 
  SELECT 4, 'test_time', SUM(test_time) 
  FROM taleParker
```

**Update:** in SQL Server 2008, you could have:

```
INSERT #tableN (ID,NAME,Value) 
   VALUES(1, 'subject', 1), (2, 'age', 42), (3, 'sex', 'M') .....
```

but then you have to use fixed values - not `SELECT` expressions

**Update #2:** if you want to use a `SUM(...)` value, you'd have to get those first into variables:

```
DECLARE @SumSubj INT, @SumAge INT, @SumSex INT, @SumTest INT

SELECT @SumSubj = SUM(subject), @SumAge = SUM(age),
       @SumSex = SUM(sex), @SumTest = SUM(test_time)
FROM taleParker

INSERT #tableN (ID,NAME,Value) 
   VALUES(1, 'subject', @SumSubj), (2, 'age', @SumAge), (3, 'sex', @SumSex) .....
```

Comment: Can this be fixed with the `INSERT #tableN (ID,NAME,Value) SELECT VALUES(...)`

Comment: @darkcminor: no. You **either** have an `INSERT #tableN(...) VALUES(.....)` - or then you have `INSERT INTO #tableN(...) SELECT .....` but you **cannot** mix the two.

Comment: @darkcminor, yes there is. See my answer below.

Comment: One more question, as you say fixed values, If I do a select statement for the third field SELECT SUM(subject), Is there a way to do something like you said:`INSERT #tableN (ID,NAME,Value) 
   VALUES(1, 'subject', SELECT SUM(subject) from A_table), (2, 'age', SELECT SUM(age) from A_table2),...` ?? or I am just getting some high

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT #tableN (ID,NAME,Value) 
  SELECT 1, 'subject', SUM(subject) FROM taleParker  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'age', SUM(age) FROM taleParker  UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'sex', SUM(sex) FROM taleParker UNION ALL 
  SELECT 4, 'test_time', SUM(test_time) FROM taleParker
```

Comment: if I do this for lets say 1000 values, which answer outperforms: the single one with `UNION ALL` or write a lot of `INSERT` statements??

Comment: The one with UNION ALL, most likely. But you should test it yourself to be sure.